# Getting fresh result set using Laravel's Query Builder

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, query-builder

When I create this query:

```
$data = DB::table('data')
        ->leftJoin('urls', 'data.url_id', '=', 'urls.id')
        ->where('urls.tag', $tag)
        ->where('urls.requester_id', $requester_id)
        ->orderBy('data.created_at')
        ->take(100);
```

And then get the first row to perform some validations on it:

```
$sample = $data->first();
```

Any subsequent calls will only return that first row, even if I use `get()`:

```
$all_rows = $data->get();
```

I tried doing the following but it does not prevent the loss of the rest of the result set in `$data`:

```
$first = $data;
$sample = $first->first();

$all_rows = $data->get(); // Still results in the same contents as `$sample`
```

Also tried this, but same results:

```
$all_rows = $data->getFresh();
```

What's going on here and how do I get around this?

Comment: What's your issue? Please describe it in detail.

Comment: the above code should work. how are you passing data to the controller?

Comment: @itachi yes, I would think it should. There is nothing being passed to a controller. This is a command that just generates a CSV file.

Comment: post the whole code....

Comment: @itachi You're looking at it. Literally, I didn't get any further than this because of this issue. The only difference is that at the end of this is a `dd($all_rows, $sample)` and before that I manually set the value of `$tag` and `$requester_id`.

Comment: i reproduced your code and it worked as expected though.... some thing in your code is messing it up.

Comment: @itachi I did just notice that a `take()` method was tacked onto the end that I didn't copy in, but I don't see any other differences. If I do `dd($data->first(), $data->get())` then I get 1 row for each dump. If I do `dd($data->get(), $data->first())` I get 100 rows and 1 row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data = DB::table('data')
      ->leftJoin('urls', 'data.url_id', '=', 'urls.id')
      ->where('urls.tag', $tag)
      ->where('urls.requester_id', $requester_id)
      ->orderBy('data.created_at')
      ->get();
```

Will return all data which match with your expected. And the following will be the first result.

```
$first = $data->first();
```

Read about [get()](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_get) and [first()](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_first) on doc.

`->get()` return an array so you can try like the following also

```
$first = $data[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = DB::table('data')
      ->leftJoin('urls', 'data.url_id', '=', 'urls.id')
      ->where('urls.tag', $tag)
      ->where('urls.requester_id', $requester_id)
      ->orderBy('data.created_at')
      ->get();

$sample = $data[0];
```